# What is this 5' Tall Pipe on the Side of my house (1973/South Florida)?

Tags: pipe

I just bought a home built in 1973 in South Florida. There is a pipe protruding from the ground on the side of my house with all the utilities. It's about 5 feet high. Any idea what it is? Who should I call to find out? The county? I appreciate any advice. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I take it you're on municipal utilities for everything?

Comment: You might try getting back with the previous owners.  Maybe they started drilling for a sprinkler pump and never completed it..

Comment: Perhaps you should have found this out before completing the purchase... I would.

Comment: Yes, municipal utilities for everything.

Comment: Do other houses in the neighborhood have these?  Perhaps it's a vent for an underground room?

Comment: If a clown holding balloons pops up,  move away.

Comment: Is it crooked like that or is that an optical illusion? If it's leaning, it smacks of some DYI project. Also, is there a basement (unlikely in Florida)? If so, it may have been an outlet for a radon gas vent system, popular some time ago.

Comment: It's very strange. My husband and I stuck our garden hose down it to see how far it would go. It's 12 feet from the top (7 feet underground). It has water inside, probably from the rain. We showed it to two plumbers, and they had no clue what it was. To answer the previous questions ..The pole is a little crooked, no basement, no other neighbors have it, and no balloons popping out.

Comment: Update: Another plumber believe that due to the depth (7 ft underground), it's likely for irrigation. We're going to bring an irrigation specialist around to look at it.